# References for Italian-American slang

Tags: american-english, slang

As an Italian, I find the interaction between my language and the English language fascinating. One big problem I am facing now is the scarceness of academic resources on the subject. Apart from some websites such as [this one from CUNY](http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/modlang/carasi/courses/ITAM.SUMMER13/itam.summer13.MATERIALS/ARTICLES/it-am-slang.htm) and blog or newspaper articles like [this one from Harvard](https://blogs.harvard.edu/ethicalesq/goomba-goombah-gumba-gumbah/), there isn't much one can read about the Italian language in an AE linguistic context.

My greatest interest lies in the sociolinguistic dynamics of said interaction, but anything that has to do with the subject will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do resource requests.

Comment: I am sorry if I broke some rule, and yet I don't understand this "we don't do X" philosophy. My question is not off-topic, has to do with both the English language and its usage - the latter more so - and has been asked kindly. Thus I humbly ask: Is it really necessary to vote to close down a question which might even be of interest to future visitors on the sole ground that "you don't do resource requests"?

Comment: *You* don't think your question is off topic, but that doesn't mean that we agree. Asking kindly doesn't mean that your question is a good fit for this site.

Comment: I understand. If so, can one please recommend another SE or website where I could ask the same question without it being rejected?

Comment: @eslukas For whatever reason, requests for resources are welcome at EL&U Meta, but not on the main site. You can flag the post and request a moderator move it there.

Comment: You could try asking over at [SE Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) but take a look at their [**help center**](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) information to see if your question is on topic. Saying that, I know there are a few Italo Americans, and Italian immigrants who might share your same passion and thirst for knowledge.

Comment: dunno if it's on topic at https://italian.stackexchange.com - might be worth a look if you haven't tried already

Comment: I sent a request for moving the question to EL&U Meta and cross-posted it on the Linguistics SE. For now I'll wait and see what happens; eventually I might cross-post it to the Italian SE and/or the Academia SE. Thanks to everybody for the suggestions!

Comment: Loanwords in English from Italian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Italian_origin